# I am implementing sitemesh3 in my spring MVC project and getting 404 exception

Tags: spring, templates, spring-mvc, sitemesh

I am implementing sitemesh3 in my spring MVC project and getting 404 exception. I am following this tutorial [SiteMesh3](http://www.sitemesh.org/getting-started.html) now the problem is I am placing my jsp's inside Web-Inf in view Folder so what path i should give in sitemesh3.xml in decorator tag. I had tried a long but gettting 404 when deployed....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I successfully managed to make it work sitemesh3 + spring mvc. Decorators can be placed inside WEB-INF without problem

my directory structure is as follow

```
webapp/WEB-INF$ tree
.
├── enable-jmx.xml
├── lnramirez-servlet.xml
├── sitemesh3.xml
├── urlrewrite.xml
├── views
│   ├── about.jsp
│   ├── blog
│   │   └── list.jsp
│   ├── defaultdecorator.jsp
│   └── home.jsp
└── web.xml
```

my sitemesh3 configuration

```
$ cat sitemesh3.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="MacRoman"?>
<sitemesh>
  <mapping path="/*" decorator="/WEB-INF/views/defaultdecorator.jsp"/>
</sitemesh>
```

and my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>HiddenMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HiddenMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

beware if you're using UrlRewriteFilter filter like myself you might run into the same trouble I had. You have to place **ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter** before other filters.

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

decorators.xml:

```
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/decorators">
    <decorator name="login" page="login_master.jsp">
        <pattern>/login*</pattern>
    </decorator>
    <decorator name="none" page="none.jsp">
        <pattern>/report*</pattern>
    </decorator>
    <decorator name="master" page="master.jsp">
        <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>
```

None.jsp:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            <decorator:title />
        </title>
        <decorator:head />
    </head>
    <body>
        <decorator:body />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using sitemesh3 and I have sitemesh3.xml and not decorators.xml

Comment: have you added this filter in web.xml: <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: Kevin this configuration are for simple sitemesh and I am using sitemesh3 so its not useful for me. I had placed a link in my question please refer that to understand my problem.